# Next track shortcut for iTunes on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, keyboard-shortcuts

does anyone know that what is the shortcut of playing next track for iTunes on Windows 7?

I am using iTunes but I want to do this when iTunes is not on the screen, I want to change track when iTunes is minimized. I have keys on my keyboard (Logitech Mx3200) for this job but I want to change them and it needs key combinations for this.

Comment: It depends on your media player what global hotkey´s it supports and you keyboard might support some too. So please be more specific about what you´re using ;-)

Comment: Ok, I am using iTunes but I want to do this when iTunes is not on the screen, I wanna change track when iTunes is minimazed. I have keys on my keyboard (Logitech Mx3200) for this job but I want to change them and it needs key combinations for this.

Comment: You should include *all* relevant information when asking your question, otherwise you'll get irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to globally use keyboard shortcuts for iTunes, you need to download iTunes Hotkey. This [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/263925/control-itunes-using-keyboard-shortcuts-with-itunes-hotkey) explains how to do it. Then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to play next track.

Comment: Note for iTunes 12 and up: iTunes is now a 64-bit app, and most of these old plug-ins no longer work! However, there is still an updated one here: https://github.com/pezcode/ighp

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Media Player for the last few versions, including that in Windows 7 which is WMP 12, the keys you want are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Find a whole load more [WMP shortcut keys on the Windows team blog here](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsexperience/archive/2009/06/16/keyboard-shortcuts-for-windows-media-player-in-windows-7.aspx).